# SVN Merge returns nothing

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, merge

Here is the scenario:
Windows Vista environment.  SVN version 1.6.11.
I'm on my branch directory.
I want to update my branch with a particular change from my trunk.
Using command line (using SlikSVN) I enter the following and it returns nothing (returns a blank line and no merge occurs):

svn merge -r 11846:11891 http://**trunk/**/AppConstants.java

When I do the equivalent using Tortoise SVN, it says "Completed" but nothing gets merged either.  When I do a svn diff I clearly see the differences I want to merge in from the trunk to my branch.  The diff command I am using is svn diff -r 11846:11891 http://**trunk/**/AppConstants.java.

Can anyone figure why no merge occurs? Thanks!!!

Comment: are you in the same directory of the .java file ?

Comment: So if you use tortoise svn, right click on the AppConstants.java file and do a show log, what is the latest revision number that you see listed?

Comment: I know you already mentioned you were in the branch directory, but its an easy point to overlook so maybe run a svn info in the workspace directory to make sure you are in the exact location in the branch workspace where you need to be?

Comment: I am having thi s exact problem